# Git update-index assume unchanged - Does it push to remote

Tags: git

I've read about how people are using git update-index with --assume-unchanged to temporarily ignore some files that were "modified" but we don't want to ignore those modification.

For example, in my project I have some sort of launcher file, that comes with the standard launcher. but when the project is built locally, the launcher file's property might change but I want to "ignore" this. The usage of update-index --assume-unchanged is very tempting.

My question is, if I forget to retrack it back ie --no-assume-unchange it, and push it to remote, what are the implications?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, if I forget to retrack it back ie `--no-assume-unchange` it, and push it to remote, what are the implications?

None  (for the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)): updating the index is a purely local operation, which isn't pushed at all.